# Limited Sort/Filter Algorithm

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, filter

I have a rather large list of elements (100s of thousands).

I have a filter that can either accept or not accept elements.

I want the top 100 elements that satisfy the filter.

So far, I have sorted the results first and then taken the top 100 that satisfy the filter.  The rationale behind this is that the filter is not entirely fast.

But right now, the sorting step is taking way longer than the filtering step, so I would like to combine them in some way.

Is there an algorithm to combine the concerns of sorting/filtering to get the top 100 results satisfying the filter without incurring the cost of sorting all of the elements?

Comment: How would you define "top" without sorting?

Comment: @dlev: You still have to sort... you just don't have to sort the *entire* collection if you know you're only going to need a few of the "highest" values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My instinct is to select the top 100 elements from the list (much cheaper than a sort, use your favorite variant of QuickSelect). Run those through the filter, yielding `n` successes and `100-n` failures. If `n < 100` then repeat by selecting `100-n` elements from the top of the remainder of the list:

```
k = 100
while (k > 0):
    select top k from list and remove them
    filter them, yielding n successes
    k = k - n
```

All being well this runs in time proportional to the length of the list, since each selection step runs in that time, and the number of selection steps required depends on the success rate of the filter, but not directly on the size of the list.

I expect this has some bad cases, though. If almost all elements fail the filter then it's considerably slower than just sorting everything, since you'll end up selecting thousands of times. So you might want some criteria to bail out if it's looking bad, and fall back to sorting the whole list.

It also has the problem that it will likely do a largeish number of small selects towards the end, since we expect k to decay exponentially if the filter criteria are unrelated to the sort criteria. So you could probably improve it by selecting somewhat more than k elements at each step. Say, k divided by the expected success rate of the filter, plus a small constant. The expectation based on past performance if there's no domain knowledge you can use to predict it, and the small constant chosen experimentally to avoid an annoyingly large number of steps to find the last few elements. If you end up at any step with more items that have passed the filter than the number you're still looking for (i.e, n > k), then select the top k from the current batch of successes and you're done.

Since QuickSelect gives you the top k without sorting those k, you'll need to do a final sort of 100 elements if you need the top 100 in order.

Comment: +1 This is EXACTLY what I was going to write.  For completeness - the expected runtime is O(np + k log k) time and O(np) filter applications, where p is the probability of any element passing the filter.  You don't need to grow exponentially with the size of the window, BTW - if you assume that the elements pass the filter independently with probability p, then the probability does drop off exponentially.

Comment: Yes, my nightmare scenario "almost all elements fail the filter" can only be true as the list gets longer, if the filter is not independent of the list length and sort order of the elements, but in fact gets more picky in bigger versions of the problem. Dealing with any such inter-relation is kind of beyond the scope of a simple complexity analysis, I think. So I'm happy with your assumption of independence for that purpose, and assuming it fully would save worrying about that killer case.

Comment: Actually, isn't `p` in your comment the probability of an element *failing* the filter? That is, if the filter accepts most things then we should require fewer applications of the filter, not more.

Comment: I like this solution, though I agree that you should not be selecting k at each step, because the nightmare that you get 99 that pass on the first hit and the next one to pass happens to have the worst score, you've got basically n^2 happening.
I'm likely going to do it in constant sized chunks as the filter's success probability depends to a great degree on the user performing the search.

Comment: Also, if we expect a certain percent to fail, it might make sense to make the initial select larger than k.
I am going to experiment with various chunking methods and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this exact problem by using a binary tree for sorting and by keeping count of the elements to the left of the current node during insertion. See http://pub.uni-bielefeld.de/publication/2305936 (Figure 4.4 et al) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you have two choiced:

- Selecting 100 Elements - N operations of the filter check. Then 100(lg 100) for the sort.
- Sorting then selecting 100 Elements - At least N(lg N) for the sort, then the select.

the first sounds shorter then sorting then selecting.

Comment: Though filtering the entire list is asymptotic-time faster, the actual act of filtering has a non-trivial cost associated with it.  At a certain critical point, filtering first is faster but for most cases sorting first is faster.
I think the solution accepted addresses these two concerns fairly elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably filter first, then insert the result of that into a priority queue. Keep track of the number of items in the PQ, and after you do the insert, if it's larger than the number you want to keep (100 in your case), pop off the smallest item and discard it.

Answer (score 0):

Steve's suggestion to use Quicksort is a good one.

1 Read in the first 1000 or so elements.
2 Sort them and pick the 100th largest element.
3 Run one pass of Quicksort on the whole file with the element from step 2 as the pivot.
4 Select the upper half of the result of the Quicksort pass for further processing.

You are guaranteed at least 100 elements in the upper half of the single pass of Quicksort.  Assuming the first 1000 are reasonably representative of the whole file then you should end up with about one tenth of the original elements at step 4.

Comment: I suggested Quickselect (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect#Partition-based_general_selection_algorithm), not Quicksort. The step of partitioning around a pivot is the same, but quickselect uses it just to find the top `k` elements, it doesn't sort the data.

Comment: My error.  Sorry.  That is the same point I was trying to make with my "one pass of Quicksort" phrase.